# Why can't this Emberjs controller set a key

Tags: ember.js

Below is a reduced Ember controller. jQuery is used to make a remote call, and action needs to be taken in the controller in the callback.

In the callback, `this` refers to the GenericController correctly, I can read a value with `this.get('someKey')` but `this.set('someKey', '')` will not set the value. This works when the `this.transitionTo` method is removed. Any help on how to get the set to work with a transition present would be super helpful.

```
App.GenericController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  someAction: function() {
    var jqxhr = jQuery.getJSON(this._endpoint, {someKey: this.get('someKey')});
    jqxhr.done(this._someActionComplete.bind(this));
  },

  _endpoint: '/some/generic.json',

  _someActionComplete: function(json, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    this.set('someKey', '');
    this.transitionToRoute('reference', reference);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It' all about async.

When you invoke your method `this` correctly references the controller as you already noticed, this is why you can use `this.get('someValue')`, but by the time the ayncronous call returns (wenn `done` is invoked for example) `this` no longer references your controller anymore but the object which invoked the `done` function, so you have to safe the correct reference to `this` before you make the request, this way you can use it to pass it to the `bind` function:

```
App.GenericController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  someAction: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var jqxhr = jQuery.getJSON(this._endpoint, {someKey: this.get('someKey')});
    jqxhr.done(_this._someActionComplete(_this));
  },

  _endpoint: '/some/generic.json',

  _someActionComplete: function(json, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    this.set('someKey', '');
  }
});
```

### Update in response to your last comment

I don't know what you are doing differently, but take a look at this simple [Demo](http://jsbin.com/idefaw/5/edit) that it works as expected. Click the button "Some action" to execute the request.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was another approach I took while battling Ember, and sadly it too does not get the job done.

Comment: @danott, added a simple demo to my answer, have a look

Comment: Definitely bizarre - your demo is working perfectly. I read an obscure post somewhere that makes me suspect that it may be a behavior related to jQuery versioning. I believe I am using a different version of jQuery than your demo...will try later and confirm if that is indeed the culprit.

Comment: Actually - just tried it in your Demo fiddle. Changed jQuery version to 1.10.0 - and it no longer worked. Definitely need to lock my app at jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: On seconds look, that is only part of the problem. The other part deals with controller.transitionTo...updating the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` in `jqxhr.done` does not reference the `GenericController`, it references the object that invoked `done`. This is how I solve it:

```
App.GenericController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  someAction: function() {
  var self = this;
    var jqxhr = jQuery.getJSON(this._endpoint, {someKey: this.get('someKey')});
    jqxhr.done(self._someActionComplete.bind(self));
  }
}
```

Now you still have a reference to `this` you can use to call other functions, including `set`, on the controller.

Comment: This was another approach I took while battling Ember, and sadly it too does not get the job done.